# How to receive data only from last subscriber with Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine

I have singleton class, which stores MutableSharedFlow.

Also I have several Screens, and they are subscribed to the flow.

```
object Messages {
  val messages = MutableSharedFlow<String>()
}

class FirstViewModel {
    init {
       viewModelScope.launch {
          Messages.messages.collect {
          Log.d("FIRST: $it")
          }
       }
    }
}

class SecondViewModel {
    init {
       viewModelScope.launch {
          Messages.messages.collect {
          Log.d("SECOND: $it")
          }
       }
    }
}
```

Whenever new data pushesh to messages, all subscribers recevies it.

I want to receive data only from last subscriber.

Comment: This is not directly supported. You probably need to build some sort of queue of subscribers and internally delegate to the top listener on the stack.